# Swift 3: Filtering results with ID's and reload tableview

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to figure how to filter the data and reload the tableview.

I have 4 regions (North, South, East and West) and all.

By default, it will show all the profiles.

If I press North (i.e. 1), it should only filter profiles available in the North Region

Similarly, with south, east and west. Depending on the region pressed, it should filter the profile.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        let cell = self.bussinessTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bussinessCell", for: indexPath) as! BussinessCell

        let tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriezTwo = subCatagorizeDataTwo[indexPath.row]

        let charCheck = (tableObjects.address).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        cell.bussinessWebView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

        var strings = ""

        if regId == 1
        {
            cell.bussinessName.text = " "
            let tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriezTwoNorth = subCatagorizeDataTwoN[indexPath.row]

            if tableObjects.address.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                 strings = strings+(tableObjects.nameString.characters.count > 0 ? "<font size=\"3\"><b>"+tableObjects.nameString+"</b></font><br>" : "")
            }
            else
            {
                //nothing
            }
            if tableObjects.telephone.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.telephone.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;' src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/mobile.gif\"> "+tableObjects.telephone+"<br>" : "")
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.email.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.email.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;'  src=\"http://localbluepages.com.au/images/icons/email.gif\"> "+tableObjects.email+"<br>" : "")
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.website.characters.isEmpty != true{
                 strings = strings+(tableObjects.website.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;'  src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/website.gif\"> "+tableObjects.website : "")
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        else if regId == 2
        {
            cell.bussinessName.text = " "
            let tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriezTwoEast = subCatagorizeDataTwoE[indexPath.row]
            //cell.bussinessName.text = tableObjects.nameString
            if tableObjects.address.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
              //  cell.bussinessName.text = tableObjects.nameString
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.nameString.characters.count > 0 ? "<font size=\"3\"><b>"+tableObjects.nameString+"</b></font><br>" : "")
            }
            else
            {
                //nothing
            }
            if tableObjects.telephone.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.telephone.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;' src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/mobile.gif\"> "+tableObjects.telephone+"<br>" : "")
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.email.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.email.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;'  src=\"http://localbluepages.com.au/images/icons/email.gif\"> "+tableObjects.email+"<br>" : "")
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.website.characters.isEmpty != true{
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.website.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;'  src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/website.gif\"> "+tableObjects.website : "")
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        else if regId == 3
        {
            cell.bussinessName.text = " "
            let tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriezTwoSouth = subCatagorizeDataTwoS[indexPath.row]
           // cell.bussinessName.text = tableObjects.nameString
            if tableObjects.address.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                //cell.bussinessName.text = tableObjects.nameString
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.nameString.characters.count > 0 ? "<font size=\"3\"><b>"+tableObjects.nameString+"</b></font><br>" : "")
            }
            else
            {
                //nothing
            }
            if tableObjects.telephone.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.telephone.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;' src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/mobile.gif\"> "+tableObjects.telephone+"<br>" : "")
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.email.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.email.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;'  src=\"http://localbluepages.com.au/images/icons/email.gif\"> "+tableObjects.email+"<br>" : "")
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.website.characters.isEmpty != true{
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.website.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;'  src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/website.gif\"> "+tableObjects.website : "")
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        else if regId == 4
        {
            cell.bussinessName.text = " "
            let tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriezTwoWest = subCatagorizeDataTwoW[indexPath.row]
        //    cell.bussinessName.text = tableObjects.nameString
            if tableObjects.address.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
              //  cell.bussinessName.text = tableObjects.nameString
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.nameString.characters.count > 0 ? "<font size=\"3\"><b>"+tableObjects.nameString+"</b></font><br>" : "")
            }
            else
            {
                //nothing
            }
            if tableObjects.telephone.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.telephone.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;' src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/mobile.gif\"> "+tableObjects.telephone+"<br>" : "")
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.email.characters.isEmpty != true
            {
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.email.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;'  src=\"http://localbluepages.com.au/images/icons/email.gif\"> "+tableObjects.email+"<br>" : "")
            }
            else
            {

            }
            if tableObjects.website.characters.isEmpty != true{
                strings = strings+(tableObjects.website.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;'  src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/website.gif\"> "+tableObjects.website : "")
            }

        }
        else{
            let tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriezTwo = subCatagorizeDataTwo[indexPath.row]
            cell.bussinessName.text = tableObjects.nameString

            let charCheck = (tableObjects.address).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
            print(charCheck)
            cell.bussinessName.text = " "

            var strings = ""

            strings = strings+(tableObjects.nameString.characters.count > 0 ? "<font size=\"3\"><b>"+tableObjects.nameString+"</b></font><br>" : "")
            strings = strings+(tableObjects.nameString.characters.count > 0 ? "<font size=\"3\"><b>"+tableObjects.address+"</b></font><br>" : "")
            // strings = strings+(tableObjects.address.characters.count > 0 ? "<img src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/yt.jpg\"> "+tableObjects.address+"<br>" : "")

            strings = strings+(tableObjects.telephone.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;' src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/mobile.gif\"> "+tableObjects.telephone+"<br>" : "")

            strings = strings+(tableObjects.email.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;'  src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/email.gif\"> "+tableObjects.email+"<br>" : "")

            strings = strings+(tableObjects.website.characters.count > 0 ? "<img style='width:22px; height:22px;'  src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/website.gif\"> "+tableObjects.website : "")

            // cell.bussinessWebView.loadHTMLString("<font size=\"5\"><b>"+tableObjects.nameString+"</b></font><br><img src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/yt.jpg\"> "+tableObjects.address+"<br><img src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/mobile.gif\"> "+tableObjects.telephone+"<br><img src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/email.gif\"> "+tableObjects.email+"<br><img src=\"http://getmydetails.pe.hu/img/website.gif\"> "+tableObjects.website, baseURL: nil)

            cell.bussinessWebView.loadHTMLString(strings, baseURL: nil)
            let heightIndex = strings.components(separatedBy: "<br>")
            let heightMul = heightIndex.count
            print(heightMul*32)

            self.heightOfTheCell = CGFloat(((heightMul)*32)+4)


        }
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.section == 1
    {
        let cell = self.bussinessTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bussinessCell2")
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        switch regId
        {
        case 0:
            if subCatagorizeDataTwo.count != forAll
            {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "LOAD MORE DATA"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = Color.whiteColor
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

            }else{
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "NO MORE FOUND!"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            }
        case 1:
            if subCatagorizeDataTwoN.count != forN
            {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "LOAD MORE DATA"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = Color.whiteColor
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

            }else{
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "NO MORE FOUND!"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            }
        case 2:
            if subCatagorizeDataTwoE.count != forE
            {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "LOAD MORE DATA"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = Color.whiteColor
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

            }else{
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "NO MORE FOUND!"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            }
        case 3:
            if subCatagorizeDataTwoS.count != forS
            {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "LOAD MORE DATA"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = Color.whiteColor
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

            }else{
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "NO MORE FOUND!"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            }
        case 4:
            if subCatagorizeDataTwoW.count != forW
            {
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "LOAD MORE DATA"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = Color.whiteColor
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

            }else{
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "NO MORE FOUND!"
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
                cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            }

        default:break
        }

        return cell!
    }
    else
    {
        let tableObjects:StorageSubCatagoriez3rd = SubCatagoriez3rd[indexPath.row]
        let cell = self.bussinessTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bussinessCell3")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = tableObjects.nameString
        return cell!

    }
}
```

Please see the screenshot:

[image: When Displaying all]

[image: When Displaying South Region]

And, as seen in the second Screenshot (South Region) the profile was meant to  be hidden as it belongs to North region.

Please let me know how can I fix this.

Thanks for the time :)

Model:

```
class StorageSubCatagoriezTwo
{
var nameString:String
var idString:String
var address:String
var telephone:String
var email:String
var website:String

init(tempName:String,tempID:String,tempaddress:String,tempTelephone:String,tempEmail:String,tempWebsite:String)
{
    self.nameString = tempName.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.idString  = tempID.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.address = tempaddress.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.telephone = tempTelephone.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.email = tempEmail.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.website = tempWebsite.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
}
}

    class StorageSubCatagoriezTwoNorth

{
var nameString:String
var idString:String
var address:String
var telephone:String
var email:String
var website:String

init(tempName:String,tempID:String,tempaddress:String,tempTelephone:String,tempEmail:String,tempWebsite:String)
    {
    self.nameString = tempName.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.idString  = tempID.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.address = tempaddress.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.telephone = tempTelephone.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.email = tempEmail.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.website = tempWebsite.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
}
}

class StorageSubCatagoriezTwoEast
{
var nameString:String
var idString:String
var address:String
var telephone:String
var email:String
var website:String

init(tempName:String,tempID:String,tempaddress:String,tempTelephone:String,tempEmail:String,tempWebsite:String)
{
    self.nameString = tempName.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.idString  = tempID.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.address = tempaddress.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.telephone = tempTelephone.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.email = tempEmail.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.website = tempWebsite.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
}
}

class StorageSubCatagoriezTwoWest
{
var nameString:String
var idString:String
var address:String
var telephone:String
var email:String
var website:String

init(tempName:String,tempID:String,tempaddress:String,tempTelephone:String,tempEmail:String,tempWebsite:String)
{
    self.nameString = tempName.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.idString  = tempID.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.address = tempaddress.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.telephone = tempTelephone.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.email = tempEmail.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.website = tempWebsite.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)    }
}

class StorageSubCatagoriezTwoSouth
{
var nameString:String
var idString:String
var address:String
var telephone:String
var email:String
var website:String

init(tempName:String,tempID:String,tempaddress:String,tempTelephone:String,tempEmail:String,tempWebsite:String)
{
    self.nameString = tempName.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.idString  = tempID.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.address = tempaddress.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.telephone = tempTelephone.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.email = tempEmail.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    self.website = tempWebsite.trimmingCharacters(in:  CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
}
}
```

Fetching Region and Assigning to the var:

```
let id = String(describing: dictionary["id"]!)
                        let name = String(describing: dictionary["BUSINESS_NAME"]!)
                        let email = String(describing: dictionary["EMAIL"]!)
                        var streetNo = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NO"]!)
                        var streetName = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NAME"]!)
                        var suburbID = String(describing: dictionary["SUBURB_ID"]!)
                        var postCode = String(describing: dictionary["POSTCODE"]!)
                        let regionID = String(describing: dictionary["REGION_ID"]!)
                        var landline = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_FIXED"]!)
                        var mobile = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_MOBILE"]!)
                        let website = String(describing: dictionary["WEBURL"]!)
                        var suburbName = String(describing: dictionary["Suburb"]!)
                        let streedNoHide = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NO_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let streetNameHide = String(describing: dictionary["STREET_NAME_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let suburbHide = String(describing: dictionary["SUBURB_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let postCodeHide = String(describing: dictionary["POSTCODE_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let mobileHide = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_MOBILE_HIDDEN"]!)
                        let landlineHide = String(describing: dictionary["PHONE_FIXED_HIDDEN"]!)
```

JSON DATA: (REGION_ID)

[image]

Comment: Can you add your Category model ?

Comment: How you identify that which profile belongs to which region ?

Comment: Where in code are you setting value of regId?

Comment: region ID is read from the external database

Comment: @Jaydeep, please review the code. I have updated it!!

Comment: So which field in model is matched with your external region Id?

Comment: @Jaydeep, please find the code above.  I have updated my code. Region ID get the data from the REGION_ID (let regionID = String(describing: dictionary["REGION_ID"]!))

Comment: So what is value of this regionID, is it a combination of random characters or like north, south...etc ?

Comment: @Surjeet, there are four ID's. 1 = North, 2 = East, 3 = South and 4 = West

Comment: @Surjeet, please check the JSON data screen shot

Comment: @Surjeet, if you use postman: please check the data by pasting the link in it: http://www.localbluepages.com.au/app/database/subcat_to_bus_results.php     (using Key = id and value = 12900)

Comment: @Surjeet  can you help me to fix the issue please?

Comment: @Jaydeep  can you help me to fix the issue please?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Their should be 2 different array.

```
var mainArray = [StorageSubCatagories]()
var filteredArray = [StorageSubCatagories]()
```

**1st array to having all objects.** (mainArray)

**2nd array to have only filtred objects from main array.** (filteredArray)

**2)** **You should use common class like 'StorageSubCatagories'** to parse all data **instead of using** multiple classes like StorageSubCatagoriezTwo, StorageSubCatagoriezTwoNorth, StorageSubCatagoriezTwoEast...etc, and **store all objects into a single array** like below:

**3)** 
    This function will return you filtered data according to button selection. 
For button all pass regionId = 0, and for north regionId = 1,.... as per your values.

```
 func fetchResultForSelection(_ regionId: Int) -> [StorageSubCatagories] {
       if regionId == 0 {
           return mainArray
       } 
       let tempArray = mainArray.filter { $0.regId == regionId }
       return tempArray
    }
```

add objects of array returned from this function into filteredArray after removing previous objects.

**4) Always display your table data based on filteredArray instead of mainArray.**

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks Surjeet. I will try this. Lets see

Comment: hey, I tried the solution recommended by you, but apparently, it's still not working.

Comment: How many objects you received from this func fetchResultForSelection ?

Comment: I dont have this func

Comment: Is that ok, if I can email you the file?

Comment: I mean, if I can email you the project?

Comment: Or if you have teamviewer? I can share the code with you

Comment: I have identified the problem. When I tap on the regions, my table data does not gets updated. I tried using tableView reload()  but its not updating/ reloading